# How do you update a uniform In Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader

I had to re-write my question because I was asking the wrong thing before.

I meant to ask, how do you update a uniform in three.js?

Comment: You appear to have it backwards. It is the uniforms that are updated every frame.

Comment: Oh oops you are right I got the terminology wrong. I guess my question really is, how do I update a float uniform without using a Vector2 or Vector3? And I assume however you do that is better.

Comment: I think i found it. is it: yourMesh.material.uniforms.yourUniform.value = whatever; ? Are there any performance issues I need to watch out for?

Comment: All uniforms have a type and a value. Update the `.value`

Comment: I think you are being too quick to post here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
yourMesh.material.uniforms.yourUniform.value = whatever;
```

Answer (score 7):

There are 2 Ways:

- You can update `uniform` in `Shader Material` itself

  OR
- you can use `mesh.material` to access the `ShaderMaterial`and then update the `uniform`

  **Example of both cases:**

  ```
     var  delta = 0
     var customUniforms = {
      delta: { value: 0 },
      u_time: { value: Date.now() }
     };

      // shader material with custom Uniform
      shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        uniforms: customUniforms,
        vertexShader: document.getElementById("vertexShader2").textContent,
        fragmentShader: document.getElementById("fragmentShader2").textContent
      });

      // test Mesh object for shader
      var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10);
      shaderMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, shaderMaterial);
      this.scene.add(shaderMesh);
  ```

  In animate loop

  ```
    animate = () => {
      delta += 0.1; 

            // Update uniform in Shader Material
            shaderMaterial.uniforms.delta.value = 0.5 + Math.sin(delta) * 0.0005;

            // Update uniform from Mesh itself
       shaderMesh.material.uniforms.u_time.value = delta;

  }
  ```

https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-http-e9wk5

[image]

**Complete Example**

```
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
    <script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        void main() {
            gl_Position = vec4( position, 1.0 );
        }
    </script>
    <script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        uniform vec2 u_resolution;
        uniform float u_time;

        void main() {
            vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;
            gl_FragColor=vec4(st.x,st.y,0.0,1.0);
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        var container;
        var camera, scene, renderer;
        var uniforms;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {
            container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

            camera = new THREE.Camera();
            camera.position.z = 1;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 2, 2 );

            uniforms = {
                u_time: { type: "f", value: 1.0 },
                u_resolution: { type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2() },
                u_mouse: { type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2() }
            };

            var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
                uniforms: uniforms,
                vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
                fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent
            } );

            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add( mesh );

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );

            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            onWindowResize();
            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            document.onmousemove = function(e){
              uniforms.u_mouse.value.x = e.pageX
              uniforms.u_mouse.value.y = e.pageY
            }
        }

        function onWindowResize( event ) {
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            uniforms.u_resolution.value.x = renderer.domElement.width;
            uniforms.u_resolution.value.y = renderer.domElement.height;
        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();
        }

        function render() {
            uniforms.u_time.value += 0.05;
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Little example updating the shader uniform.

```
/* Vertex Shader */
<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="myShader">
    uniform float myuniform;
    uniform sampler2D myTexture;
    varying vec2 vUV;
    varying vec2 ver;

    ver = uv *vec2( myuniform,  myuniform); // this will be updated on mouse move        

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix *modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
</script>

/* Set uniform */
var myUniform;
var myTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( './data/textures/theTexture.jpg'  );
    _uniforms = {
    myUniform:  { type: "f", value: myUniform },        
    myTexture:  { type: "t", value: myTexture },
};

customMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( 
{
    uniforms: _uniforms,
    vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'myShader' ).textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent,
    wireframe: false,
    side: THREE.FrontSide 

}   );

document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

function onDocumentMouseMove(ev) {
   uniforms.myUniform.value += 0.01; // Updates this new value
   uniforms.myUniform.needsUpdate = true;
}

...
```

Answer (score 1):

This seemed like a good way to do it for my use case:

```
const mat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
        customVec3Uniform: { value: new THREE.Vector3(1,1,1) }
    },
    vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexShader').textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentShader').textContent,
});
```

As for updating during runtime ([citation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51540758/332578)):

```
mat.uniforms.customVec3Uniform.value = new THREE.Vector3(2,2,2);
// mat.needsUpdate = true; // my example works without 'needsUpdate'
```

Answer (score 0):

**For those not using THREE.ShaderMaterial**

If for example you are modifying a material beyond just THREE.ShaderMaterial, say THREE.MeshStandardMaterial, via edits to its fragment shader, you will need to do things somewhat differently.

In order to modify this shader's uniforms, WITHOUT requiring recompilation, you will need to store a reference to that shader within the onBeforeCompile callback, then access those uniforms via that stored reference's uniforms.

**Typescript class:**

First plug into THREE.Material's onBeforeCompile hook transferring the values stored somewhere (in my case a uniforms dictionary created in the constructor) into the shader's uniforms. This is important because shader compilation takes place prior to first usage. Store a reference to the shader in your class for access. Do any of your other work to the fragment shader using these uniforms as you see fit.

```
private _uniforms: { [uniform: string]: ShaderUniform } = {};
private _shader?:THREE.Shader;

this._material.onBeforeCompile = (shader) => {
    let prepend = "";
    //transfer any changes occurring prior to compilation, 
    //and also prepend these shaders to the fragment shader 
    Object.entries(this._uniforms).forEach(([key, info]) => {
       prepend += `uniform ${info.type} ${key};\n`
       shader.uniforms[key] = {value: info.value};
    });
    //prepend these shaders, along with any other work to the 
    //fragment shader via basic string substitutions 
    shader.fragmentShader = prepend + shader.fragmentShader;
    //store a reference to the shader
    this._shader = shader;
}
```

Get or set the property from the stored uniforms if not compiled yet, otherwise use the shader's own uniform value, which only exists after compilation.

```
public getUniform(name:string) : any {
    return this._shader ? this._shader.uniforms[name].value : this._uniforms[name].value;
}

public setUniform(name:string, value:any) {
   if (this._shader) {
       return this._shader.uniforms[name].value = value
   } else {
       this._uniforms[name].value = value;
   }
}
```