# Three.js: Update texture passed as RawShaderMaterial uniform after initial render

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a Three.js scene that passes a canvas as a uniform to a RawShaderMaterial. After the initial scene renders, I alter the canvas (in the case below, I just paint the canvas red). I then indicate that the shaderMaterial `.needsUpdate = true;` but no color appears on the points.

Color does appear on the points if I move the `ctx.fill();` loop above the `var material =` declaration.

Does anyone know what one must do to update a canvas after the initial render when using the RawShaderMaterial? Any help others can offer would be hugely helpful!

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #000; }
  body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
  canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/88/three.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://rawgit.com/YaleDHLab/pix-plot/master/assets/js/trackball-controls.js'></script>

    <script type='x-shader/x-vertex' id='vertex-shader'>
    precision highp float;

    uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
    uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

    uniform vec3 cameraPosition;

    attribute vec3 position; // sets the blueprint's vertex positions
    attribute vec3 translation; // x y translation offsets for an instance
    attribute float texIdx; // the texture index to access

    varying float vTexIdx;

    void main() {
      // set point position
      vec3 pos = position + translation;
      vec4 projected = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0);
      gl_Position = projected;

      // assign the varyings
      vTexIdx = texIdx;

      // use the delta between the point position and camera position to size point
      float xDelta = pow(projected[0] - cameraPosition[0], 2.0);
      float yDelta = pow(projected[1] - cameraPosition[1], 2.0);
      float zDelta = pow(projected[2] - cameraPosition[2], 2.0);
      float delta  = pow(xDelta + yDelta + zDelta, 0.5);
      gl_PointSize = 40000.0 / delta;
    }
    </script>

    <script type='x-shader/x-fragment' id='fragment-shader'>
    precision highp float;

    uniform sampler2D a;
    uniform sampler2D b;

    varying float vTexIdx;

    void main() {
      int textureIndex = int(vTexIdx);
      vec2 uv = vec2(gl_PointCoord.x, gl_PointCoord.y);
      if (textureIndex == 0) {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(a, uv);
      } else if (textureIndex == 1) {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(b, uv);
      }
    }
    </script>

  <script>

  /**
  * Generate a scene object with a background color
  **/

  function getScene() {
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xaaaaaa);
    return scene;
  }

  /**
  * Generate the camera to be used in the scene
  **/

  function getCamera() {
    var aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspectRatio, 0.1, 100000);
    camera.position.set(0, 1, -6000);
    return camera;
  }

  /**
  * Generate the renderer to be used in the scene
  **/

  function getRenderer() {
    // Create the canvas with a renderer
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    // Add support for retina displays
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    // Specify the size of the canvas
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    // Add the canvas to the DOM
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    return renderer;
  }

  /**
  * Generate the controls to be used in the scene
  **/

  function getControls(camera, renderer) {
    var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.zoomSpeed = 0.4;
    controls.panSpeed = 0.4;
    return controls;
  }

  /**
  * Generate the points for the scene
  **/

  function addPoints(scene) {
    var BA = THREE.BufferAttribute;
    var IBA = THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute;
    var geometry  = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry();

    // add data for each observation
    var n = 10000; // number of observations
    var rootN = n**(1/2);
    var cellSize = 20;
    var translation = new Float32Array( n * 3 );
    var texIdx = new Float32Array( n );
    var translationIterator = 0;
    var texIterator = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<n*3; i++) {
      var x = Math.random() * n - (n/2);
      var y = Math.random() * n - (n/2);
      translation[translationIterator++] = x;
      translation[translationIterator++] = y;
      translation[translationIterator++] = Math.random() * n - (n/2);
      texIdx[texIterator++] = (x + y) > (n/8) ? 1 : 0;
    }

    var positionAttr = new BA(new Float32Array( [0, 0, 0] ), 3);
    var translationAttr = new IBA(translation, 3, 1);
    var texIdxAttr = new IBA(texIdx, 1, 1);
    positionAttr.dynamic = true;
    translationAttr.dynamic = true;
    texIdxAttr.dynamic = true;
    geometry.addAttribute('position', positionAttr);
    geometry.addAttribute('translation', translationAttr);
    geometry.addAttribute('texIdx', texIdxAttr);

    var canvases = [
      getElem('canvas', { width: 16384, height: 16384, }),
      getElem('canvas', { width: 16384, height: 16384, }),
    ];

    var material = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
      uniforms: {
        a: {
          type: 't',
          value: getTexture(canvases[0]),
        },
        b: {
          type: 't',
          value: getTexture(canvases[1]),
        }
      },
      vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertex-shader').textContent,
      fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragment-shader').textContent,
    });
    var mesh = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
    mesh.frustumCulled = false; // prevent the mesh from being clipped on drag
    scene.add(mesh);

    // Paint the canvas after the initial render
    setTimeout(function() {
      for (var i=0; i<canvases.length; i++) {
        var canvas = canvases[i];
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.fillStyle = i == 0 ? 'red' : 'blue';
        ctx.rect(0, 0, 16384, 16384);
        ctx.fill();
        // marking the material as dirty does not make the colors appear
        scene.children[0].material.needsUpdate = true;
      }
    }, 1000)
  }

  function getTexture(canvas) {
    var tex = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
    tex.needsUpdate = true;
    tex.flipY = false;
    return tex;
  }

  /**
  * Create an element
  **/

  function getElem(tag, obj) {
    var obj = obj || {};
    var elem = document.createElement(tag);
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(attr) {
      elem[attr] = obj[attr];
    })
    return elem;
  }

  /**
  * Render!
  **/

  function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    controls.update();
  };

  /**
  * Main
  **/

  var scene = getScene();
  var camera = getCamera();
  var renderer = getRenderer();
  var controls = getControls(camera, renderer);
  addPoints(scene);
  render();

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not good approach to create an instance of `THREE.Texture` in `getTexture()`. Ideally, you create the texture once and just update it like in this example: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_texture_canvas.html

Comment: Thanks very much @Mugen87 I think you just nailed a huge performance problem in this setup. I'm checking this out now...

Comment: @Mungen87 if you have a second, do you know what might be causing the scene above to take so long to reach its initial render? There are not many points. The textures passed in are large, but is that really the cause? I'd be grateful for any insights you can offer...

Comment: I've tried to run the code snippet ony my (old) laptop but I always get a WebGL context loss. Do you have a better performance if you decrease the texture resolution?

Comment: @Mungen87 strangely the performance stays roughly constant, even with a texture size of 512x512. Sorry for the context loss -- I tried to keep this sketch absolutely minimal; the real project has more bells and whistles to check for browser agent's gpu setup, but that's lots of boilerplate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, one must reassign the value of the uniform (stored in the material) and then mark the material as needing an update:

```
scene.children[0].material.uniforms.a.value = getTexture(canvases[0]);
scene.children[0].material.uniforms.b.value = getTexture(canvases[1]);
scene.children[0].material.needsUpdate = true;
```